# Radio button, dropdownlist, checkbox in ASP.NET Web Api 2 c#

Tags: html, asp.net-web-api, radio-button

I am making an ASP.NET Web Api 2 project. I am calling the Api as POST from a form.

I made a Class that implements the Form:

```
public class Form1
    {
        public bool Radio0 { get; set; }
        public bool Infrastructure { get; set; }
        public bool Loadinfrastructure1 { get; set; } ......
```

and in the form:

```
 <form action="...../api/GetInfo"  method="post">
        <div class="radio">
             <input type="radio" name="radio0" value="yes">
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
             <input type="radio" name="radio0" value="no">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 padding-bottom">
             <select name="infrastructure" id="infra">
                   <option disabled selected> -- choose -- </option>
                   <option value="">string1</option>
                   <option value="">string2</option>
                   <option value="">string3</option>
                   <option value="">string4</option>
              </select>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox block">
              <input type="checkbox" name="loadinfrastructure1" id="loadinfrastructure">
              <label for="loadinfrastructure">no</label>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and the post method:

```
public Form1 Post(Form1 model)
{
    return model;
}
```

I can call the Method and all other fields are correct but the radio button (Radio0) and the checkbox is always false, drop-down list is without a value. why and how to fix it? thank you.

Comment: How would it know that "yes" or "no" relate to some boolean values?

Comment: You should pass true false

Comment: thank you it works, well I did not do the design so I missed that part! 
but now I figure out that the dropdownlist and the checkbox are also not working! see the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. the problem with Radiobox was as mentioned in the comments:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio0" value="True">
```

value="true" instead of Yes and also false instead of No

the problem with Checkbox is that I have to add:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="loadinfrastructure1" value="true" id="loadinfrastructure">
```

have to add: value="true" To force the binder to bind the value.

the problem with dropdownlist was: 
that there is no value: (my mistake)

```
<option value="... value">string1</option>
```

hope the answer is clear! good luck for all!